# Hibernate clears @ManyToMany JoinTable when getting collection

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, join

Have two anotated classes with ManyToMany relationship. And when I try to read linked collection Hibernate return correct data, BUT, after that, deletes all rows in joinTable that is connected with object. So, after reading all connections between objects is lost.

Class Region has:

```
private Set<UserFilter> filters = new HashSet<UserFilter>();


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "regions")
public Set<UserFilter> getFilters() {
    return filters;
}

public void setFilters(Set<UserFilter> filters) {
    this.filters = filters;
}
```

Class UserFilter has:

```
private Set<Region> regions = new HashSet<Region>();


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =
        {
                javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST,
                javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE,
                javax.persistence.CascadeType.REFRESH,
                javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH
        })
@JoinTable(name = "FilterAndRegion",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "FilterId", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RegionId", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
public Set<Region> getRegions() {
    return regions;
}

public void setRegions(Set<Region> regions) {
    this.regions = regions;
}
```

When I running something like that:

```
private void updateRegionsTable() {
        //
        regionsTable.removeAllItems();
        //
        if(filter.getRegions().size() == 0 ) {
            regionsTable.addItem(new Object[]{
                            "<no regions>",
                    },
                    0
            );
        } else {
            //
            for (Region region : filter.getRegions()) {
                //
                regionsTable.addItem(new Object[]{
                                region.getName(),
                        },
                        region.getId()
                );
            }
        }
        //
        regionsTable.setPageLength(regionsTable.size());
    }
```

... in console I see:

> Hibernate: select regions0_.FilterId as FilterId1_4_0_,
>   regions0_.RegionId as RegionId2_0_0_, region1_.id as id1_2_1_,
>   region1_.CatalogName as CatalogN2_2_1_, region1_.Name as Name3_2_1_,
>   region1_.Type as Type4_2_1_ from FilterAndRegion regions0_ inner join
>   Region region1_ on regions0_.RegionId=region1_.id where
>   regions0_.FilterId=?
>
> **Hibernate: delete from FilterAndRegion where FilterId=?**

Why this happens? And how to correct this behaviour (remove clearing of joinTable)?

Comment: It comes from the code you're not showing us, and which is after the loop. You must be replacing or clearing the collection of regions somehow.

Comment: The full code of function looks like so: 
'private void updateRegionsTable() {
  regionsTable.removeAllItems();
  if(filter.getRegions.size() == 0 ) {
    regionsTable.addItem(new Object[]{"<no regions>",},0);
} else {
    for (Region region : filter.getRegions()) {
      regionsTable.addItem(new Object[] region.getName(),},region.getId());
    }
  }
  regionsTable.setPageLength(regionsTable.size());
}
'

Comment: And Hibernate settings:
hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread
hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

If this can help...

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: I've added function code to question.

Comment: Once again, the bug must be after this portion of code.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks!

Bug was in different versions of hibernate and c3p0 libraries!